# How do I install NodeJS on GuixSD?

Tags: compiling, source, guix, guixsd

How do I install NodeJS on GuixSD?

Answer (score 0):

```
guix package -i node
```

[node 10.24.0](https://guix.gnu.org/packages/node-10.24.0/)